# Kafka - Consumer speed when serialiser JSON

Tags: c#, json, apache-kafka

We are building a microservices environment which produce messages onto the queue in JSON format. When consuming these message we are using a JSON serialiser to convert this into an object in C# but because of this, each message we process including business logic takes 200-300ms to process.

Obvious for a messaging system this is a real blocker. Any ideas on how to improve this throughput? Perhaps we are taking the wrong approach entirely.

Comment: You need to run a profiler on your code to see where the majority of the time is spent, and then fix that.

Comment: Aside from the points already made, say hypothetically each message takes a long time to process for whatever reason, and can't be sped up, then this is where Kafka's approach to scaling is ideal - each consumer is working through its partition slowly, but as long as you have lots of partitions you can just add consumers to the group to get the overall throughput you want.

Comment: And this is where keys come into play if message ordering is important - as long as related messages have the same key so they go to the same partition then they can be consumed in order regardless of how much parallelism there is with consumption (though if ordering is important to you, there's a couple of bits of configuration to watch out for)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

This question seems to be about the time taken for de-serializing of JSON, this doesn't have much to do with kafka consumer.

If you spending lot of time deserializing on the kafka consumer thread, you need to fine tune max.poll.interval.ms and session.timeout.ms. You can also control the number of messages returned by max.poll.records. You need to fine tune the params.

If you feel its a lot of time for de-serializing, you should separate the business processing from consumption by putting the consumed JSON in another in memory queue and processing them parallel on separate threads ( beware of back pressure problem) and you can turn off consumer auto sync.

There is no one stop solution, analyze at the load , partition the topics accordingly and make application scalable by having multiple consumers with same group.instance.id , test to see how it goes and then only start fine tuning the params.

Comment: Thanks. Yes the slow behaviour is the JSON serialiser. My question is more driven by ways of improving this and what common pitfalls to avoid